# How to get query results for the next page

Tags: wp-query, ajax, query

How to get query for posts from next and previous pages on Blog via ajax call?

I'm thinking about making copy of the current query with offset like this:

```
$curr_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'order'          => get_query_var( 'order' ),
    'orderby'        => get_query_var( 'orderby' ),
    'post_status'    => get_query_var( 'post_status' ),
    'posts_per_page' => get_query_var( 'posts_per_page' ),
    'post_type'      => get_query_var( 'post_type' ),
    'offset'         => $offset,
) );
```

But it has too many 'get_query_var' parameters, I don't know all query_vars I need to copy to create query for the 'next page'.

Comment: Did you tried anything yet? If yes can you share it over here.

Comment: I have only idea about cloning current query with get_query_var function.

Comment: Are you trying to develop ajax based pagination?

Comment: Yes, ajax 'load more posts' button.